# Split Sentence on Punctuation or Camel-Case

Tags: python, regex, string, python-2.7, split

I have a very long string in python and i'm trying to break it up into a list of sentences. Only some of these sentences are missing puntuation and spaces between them.

Example

> I have 9 sheep in my garageVideo games are super cool.

I can't figure out the regex to separate the two! It's drive me nuts.

There are properly punctuated sentences as well, so I thought i'd make several different regex patterns, each splitting off different styles of combination.

Input

> I have 9 sheep in my garageVideo games are super cool. Some peanuts can sing, though they taste a whole lot better than they sound!

Output

> ['I have 9 sheep in my garage',
>   'Video games are super cool.'
>   'Some peanuts can sing, though they taste a whole lot better than they sound!']

Thanks!

Comment: What is the proper output for a string like "Did Dr. deArmond go down to the pharmacy?"? Splitting sentences is *hard*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Position Split: Use the `regex` module

I will give you both a "Split" and a "Match All" option. Let's start with "Split".

In many engines, but not Python's `re` module, you can split at a position defined by a zero-width match.

In Python, to split on a position, I would use Matthew Barnett's outstanding [`regex` module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex), whose features far outstrip those of Python's default `re` engine. That is my default regex engine in Python.

With your input, you can use this regex:

```
(?V1)(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])|(?<=[.!?]) +(?=[A-Z])
```

Note that if you had strangely-formatted acronyms such as `B. B. C.`, we would need to tweak this.

**Sample Python Code:**

```
string = "I have 9 sheep in my garageVideo games are super cool. Some peanuts can sing, though they taste a whole lot better than they sound!"
result = regex.split("(?V1)(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])|(?<=[.!?]) +(?=[A-Z])", string)
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
['I have 9 sheep in my garage', 
'Video games are super cool.', 
'Some peanuts can sing, though they taste a whole lot better than they sound!']
```

**Explanation**

- `(?V1)` instructs the engine to use the new behavior, where we can split on zero-width matches.
- `(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])` matches a position where the lookbehind `(?<=[a-z])` can assert that what precedes is a lower-case letter and the lookahead `(?=[A-Z])` can assert that what follows is an uppercase letter.
- `|` OR...
- `(?<=[.!?]) +(?=[A-Z])` matches one or more spaces `+` where the lookbehind `(?<=[.!?])` can assert that what precedes is a dot, bang, question mark and a space, and where the lookahead `(?=[A-Z])` can assert that what follows is a capital letter.

---

**Option 2: Use `findall` (again with the `regex` module)**

Since the "Split" and "Match All" operations are two sides of the same coin, you can do this:

```
print(regex.findall(r".+?(?:(?<=[.!?])|(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z]))",string))
```

Again, this would not work with `re` (which would skip the `V` that starts the second sentence `Video`).